# Does Pypy Support PyTables and Numpy?

Tags: python, cython, pypy, pytables, psyco

And if it doesn't, is there anyway to speed up my python code for accessing pytables on a 64-bit system (so no psyco)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some support numpy. Running pypy 1.9 I get the following message on importing numpy:

> ImportError: The 'numpy' module of PyPy is in-development and not
>   complete. To try it out anyway, you can either import from 'numpypy',
>   or just write 'import numpypy' first in your program and then import
>   from 'numpy' as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/Home

The answer is no. :(